# Jquery onmousedown needing a double click?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have searched before posting but none of the posts are that relevant (saying that i am new to Jquery).

My problem is when i click the "add friend" button it wont fire upon a single click but it needs a double click.

These are the relevant sections of code:

Setting the div:

> ```
> $fField = <div style="display:inline; border:#CCC 1px solid; padding:5px; background-color:#E4E4E4; color#999; font-size:11px;">
>   <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:friendArea(\'addFriend\');">Add Friend</a>
>   </div>;
> ```

Javascript:

```
function friendArea(x){
    //alert(x);
    if($('#'+x).is(":hidden")){
        $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $('#'+x).hide();
    }
    $('.friendSlide').hide();
}
```

the message to display (the one which needs 2 clicks to be displayed)

```
<div class="friendSlide" id="addFriend">Are you sure?</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Oh and I'm using the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: For some reason its parsing the code when i edit it :S give me 2 secs, or its missing most of it out

Comment: what is `x` that you are passing to friendArea() function?

Comment: Uh, you still have no `onclick` event assigned to your `div`, and no code for an `onclick` function.

Comment: What is `$fField`? Where is it used? It looks like a syntax error to me (without quotes around it.) As Ryan states you don't have an `onclick` handler

Comment: Indent your code 4 spaces and it won't be parsed.

Comment: Sorry @PeeHaa edited, the code above is what i should have now

Comment: Does this help: http://jsfiddle.net/VC6hK/ ?

Comment: @isotrope thats perfect! Thank you. If i wanted to add more buttons that have the same functionality would i need to make more of those?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/rSEbM/

Comment: @IanGarratt : This is a stretch from your question, but I played around a bit with what I *think* you want to add to your page: http://jsfiddle.net/VC6hK/2/

Comment: @isotrope Hey thats very nice :-) I will look at implementing that somewhere, the wonders of Jq :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, well, it looks like you are showing *and* hiding your div at the same time:

HTML:

```
<div class="friendSlide" id="addFriend">Are you sure?</div>
```

JS:

```
function friendArea(x){
    //alert(x);
    if($('#'+x).is(":hidden")){
        $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $('#'+x).hide();
    }
    $('.friendSlide').hide();
}
```

You call `friendArea('addFriend')`, which is supposed to slideDown your div, but at the end of the function you hide `.friendSlide`, of which your div is also a class.  You basically hide it *every* time.  This can't be what you want.

Comment out that line and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Ggdhp/

Of course, you might have had a different reason for that, but I think you are getting some divs and classes mixed up.

**Note:**
I would also suggest that you don't use inline css or javascript.  It always makes debug much more difficult, and you miss typos as you end up having to put everything on a single line and escape quotes.  For instance, `color#999;` in your div style is missing a colon.

Comment: Please note my added comments about inlining css and script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure that's the relevant part of the code, but if you want to learn how to bind functions to click/doubleclick/etc:

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

I assume you have a button/link somewhere that has something to the extent of:

```
<a href="#" onclick="friendArea('friendName')">Add Friend</a>
```

What you would want to do instead is give that button a class indicating that it's an add friend button, and use jQuery to add the double click function to it.

```
<a href="#" class="addFriend-button" data-friendName="friendName">Add Friend</a>

$('.addFriend-button').click( function(e) {
    friendArea( $(this).data('friendName') );
} );
```

This will cause your function to fire when the button is double clicked, not single clicked. It also allows you to only have to write 1 function, and you can pass the relevant data in using the data-* attributes on the link element.

Comment: Hi Brian, im looking for it to be fired on single click not double, at the moment its only showing the hidden box on double click

Comment: He doesn't want double-click.  He is saying that it will only fire on the second click.  He wants to know why it won't fire on the first.  I think.

Comment: Updated. All you need to do is bind on click instead of dblclick

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run any code on double click over an element use jquery like this,

```
$('#target').dblclick(function() {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

and one more thing use jquery toggle  to display and hide elements like below,
 On your function
if you are using class name of selector use the selector like below (use .) in case of id use # with id name like above code

```
$('.target').toggle();
```

if double clicks works for you   to use below code, it converts the single click to double click by jquery. Hopes this will help you

> $('#target').click(function() {
>     $('#target').dblclick();
>   });

Comment: I am looking for a single click as at the moment its only triggering on a double click